# How to ensure ajax content hosted on S3 gets indexed?

Tags: ajax, seo, amazon-s3

I have a number of sites that are completely hosted on Amazon S3 but the page is generated via JavaScript. I would like to make sure these sites are indexed by Google, but since they are hosted on S3 I don't seem to have a mechanism to serve up _escaped_fragment_ versions of the page.  Does anyone have an idea on how I could get the Ajax content indexed?  I would prefer to not have to replicate my templating server side.

Here is an example of one of my sites:
http://www.web608.org/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best practice I have seen is progressive  enhancement. Create a working page in plain html and then use JavaScript to make it cool.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm thinking I'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real easy way to do this. I'd suggest you read Google's recommendations on this topic:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: Yeah, it's a tough nut to crack. I looked at that documentation and that's the way I'd be doing it if I was hosting the sites on a normal web server, but I'm on S3 so it's not really possible.